# Capturing failed INSERT values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

Consider the following INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID, NAME, AGE)
VALUES (100, 'JOHN', 32), 
(101, 'JIM', 35), 
(102, 'SALLY', 21)
```

Assuming that a Customer record already exists for id 101, this INSERT will fail due to a primary key violation.
Is there any way to insert the valid rows, while capturing the failed row for later processing?

I'm thinking that I may have to use a cursor to process INSERTs, or use the 'MERGE' DML statement to INSERT unmatched id rows, and OUTPUT matched rows to another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written there is no way to have only the valid rows inserted to the database. The query is an implicit transaction and will be committed if successful or rolled back in the event of any  error.

To achieve the behavior you are looking for you need 4 separate INSERT statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the insert to work as written, you're going to need some sort of an instead of insert trigger that examines the INSERTED table and inserts the records that don't already exist into the actual table and inserts the duplicate rows somewhere else.